# How to add multiple URL rewrite rules in a web.config

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

How to add multiple URL  rewrite rules in a web.config

I want to match any url that contains "sales" and "registrationsuccess".

I get errors with when I try the following:

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*sales*)"/>
           <match url="(.*registrationsuccess*)"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is how you add more than one rule:

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (Sales)" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*sales*)"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (RegistrationSucces)" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*registrationsuccess*)"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But for what you're trying to do, you can do it with one rule, like below:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON" />
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^(.*)/sales/(.*)" />
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^(.*)/registrationsuccess/(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: hi all, will you please guide me for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148725/how-to-add-redirecttype-to-external-config-file-in-asp-net

Comment: @TomHall, How can I redirect all the other Pages Other Then sales and registrationsuccess to HTTP ?

Comment: I think there's an issue with the last rule logic. Since logicalGrouping="MatchAny" won't the redirect occur whether HTTPS is ON or not?