# How to add RedirectType to External config file in asp.net

Tags: redirect, web-config, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I have a separate `.config` file in the application root directory which contains `Mapped URLS for redirect` and referenced this `.config` file in `web.config` for `301 Permanent Redirect`! This works fine.

**[See Reference Link](http://xen.com.au/resources/using-rewrite-maps-in-iis-for-301-redirects/)**

***Now, i also want to add some links which will redirected as 302 status code. How to add 302 redirect in external .config file and redirect accordingly.***

**rewritemaps.config**

```
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="Redirects">
       <add key="/oldcellphone" value="/newcellphones.aspx" />
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

***Can we specify the Redirect Type i.e 301/302 in this file?***

**web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
     <rewrite>
      <rewriteMaps configSource="rewritemaps.config">
        </rewriteMaps>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent"/>
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

NOTE:Currently all links from file `'rewritemaps.config'` are set to `301 Status` in `web.config`.

**Can we add as following in rewritemaps.config and redirect accordingly:**

```
<add key="/oldcellphone" value="/newcellphones.aspx" [RedirectType=301] />
<add key="/oldphone" value="/newphones.aspx" [RedirectType=302] />
```

There are about `1000 links of 301 Status` and about `400 links for 302 Status`. If its not possible in `external file(rewritemaps.config)` then **please suggest** preferred way to do?

**Update:**
Can you help me to redirect to another site(different domain) if specific string match in requested URL .
Eg: if the requested URL contains "/hm1" then redirect to different site. i.e http://www.google.com

**Web.config**

```
<rule name="othersite" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^/hm1$" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.google.com" redirectType="Found"/>
</rule>
```

**.aspx**

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="/hm1">other site (http://www.google.com)</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add `RedirectType` into a Rewrite Map? No, unfortunately not.

To achieve what you're trying to do you're going to need to create two Rewrite Maps and two Rewrite Rules - one for 301 redirects and one for 302 redirects.

Here's an example of how that might look:

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="301Redirects" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{301Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
    </rule>
    <rule name="302Redirects" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{302Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="301Redirects">
      <add key="/oldurl" value="/newurl" />
    </rewriteMap>
    <rewriteMap name="302Redirects">
      <add key="/oldcellphone" value="/newcellphones.aspx" />
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: hi @Tom Hall, i will try this one more question can we redirect to other domain if specific string matches in requested URL ? Please see the 'Update' section in the post and guide me..!

Comment: Yes you can redirect to where ever you want.

Comment: thanks! yes this works! but my redirect to other site wont work will u plz help me ? Please see the rule i have added and help me too..? i tried to redirect to another site using above 'Rule' mentioned in "update" section but it wont work..!

Comment: @TomHall how do i translate these `apache` rules to `iis (web.config)` --> https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/htaccess-remove-php-and-keep-get-variables/40902 thank you !