# How to create rewrite rule that matches multiple URLs

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I now have this per language, but as you can see they all rewrite to the same page:

```
    <rule name="help en">
      <match url="^help?/?$"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="help.aspx"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="help sp">
      <match url="^ayuda?/?$"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="help.aspx"/>
    </rule>
```

OR more complex parameterized rewrites like:

```
<rule name="news category overview_de">
  <match url="^artikelen/([a-zA-Z0-9-+']+)?/?$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="newsoverview.aspx?category={R:1}" />
</rule>

<rule name="news category overview_en">
  <match url="^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9-+']+)?/?$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="newsoverview.aspx?category={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

This takes up a lot of space, so is there a way to write this shorter?

I checked out this post: [How to add multiple URL rewrite rules in a web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521010/how-to-add-multiple-url-rewrite-rules-in-a-web-config), but that does not make it any shorter.
Is there a way I can repeat the `match url` condition or add multiple urls to it?

**Update 1**

I tried this:

```
<rule name="news overview">
  <match url="^(artikelen|articles)?/?$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="newsoverview.aspx" />
</rule>
<rule name="news category overview">
  <match url="^(artikelen|articles)/([a-zA-Z0-9-+']+)?/?$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="newsoverview.aspx?category={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

But this now redirects even requests to my homepage to the newsoverview.aspx page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using regular expression here, so you can use:

```
^(help|ayuda|hilfe|aide)?/?$
```

so you just put the language dependent word into a OR construct:

```
^(articles|artikelen|artikel)/([a-zA-Z0-9-+']+)?/?$
```

this should work as long as the parameterized part is always the same.

Comment: Ah, tnx! How would that work with more complex parameterized rewrites? I added a sample.

Comment: Hi, see my update. All homepage requests are now also redirected using my new rewrite rules...what am I missing?

Comment: The question mark means one or none of the previous expression, so (foo)? Matches foo but also nothing. In your original match you had `help?` the question mark only applied to the p, with the brackets it applies to the whole thing, making it optional. I don't think you want that question mark there.

Comment: Ah, I thought I had to wrap the optional part between question marks :)